# Why does my 2003 honda civic lx not go past 60mph?

Tags: honda

I’ve recently bought a 2003 honda civic lx but for some reason it won’t go past 60mph. I honestly don’t have any idea why any help?

Comment: Has it been fitted with a limiter?

Comment: Does it just not accelerate past 60? Is it auto or manual

Comment: I have no idea if it has a limiter. And it’s an automatic and i can press the pedal all the way to the floor and it won’t go past 60mph. The only it goes past it is by going downhill and then it’s only gone to 63mph

Comment: fuel pump failing, clogged catalytic converter are the first causes I can think of. How many miles are on the car?